# pyspeech not working in python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7

I want to make and explore the speech to text using the python. So I searched on the google about the python speech to text api I have found pyspeech at the first and found it much easy to use but even after installing it I got some problems.

1) I have installed pyspeech using command prompt easy_install speech at the c:>python27...scripts but still i am unable to run the python speech API.

2) I have also installed the base PyPI required for the pyspeech running ez_setup.py.

Comment: Unable to run the python speech API? What error are you getting? Is "import speech" statement fails?

Comment: yes Vinayak when I run import speech on python interpreter it fails..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the import error you get? pyspeech also needs pywin32.
Is that package installed? Also check if Microsoft speech kit is installed.

If everything is fine, add sys.path.append(site package path) at the top of your code.

Comment: Really a little tweak needed to make pyspeech working thank you